# School Management system installation through C-panel error (.env file removing issue)

Tags: php, laravel, installation, cpanel

I have a school management system and I want to install in cpanel. When I upload the package in *public_html* folder and hit the URL, the installation page appears.
It checks the file permissions on first page and when I click next, moving on the next page it checks the extensions of cpanel, clicking on next button it moves to the data base credentials. When I give the credentials of data base and click on next button to install the school management system in the package *.ENV* file removed every time only *.env.exapmple* file remains but *.env* file removed. and error occured.

> WHOOPS there is something wrong

Comment: We can only guess without knowing what are you trying to install.

Comment: You have permission issue

Comment: @ZainFarooq all file permissions are ok. it asks for 775 permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Do check for show hidden files in preferences

[image]